# Dynamic generated json file read

Tags: python, scripting, file-format

I have an external script that generates a json file with rotations. I want to read this json file with blender, but it seems there is a problem with the json reading functions in blender.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('blendjson.json') as data_file: #This line throws this error : "Python script fail, look in the console for now..."  
    data = json.load(data_file)


coordx = data['coordx']
coordy = data['coordy']

#This works as long as I can get values for the varibales coordx and coordy :
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=coordx, axis=(-1, -0, -0), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=coordy, axis=(-0, -1, -0), constraint_axis=(False, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1)
```

This script works in itself when launched through the terminal (python blendjson.py), except for the bpy objects of course.
Is there a way to read the json file, or a better way to get these two variables ?

Comment: Obvious follow up question.... have you tried looking in the console for the actual python error being thrown (as it says in the error message)? In Windows you can open the console within Blender via the menu. For Linux you can launch Blender from a bash shell (or similar) and the output will be shown there. For Mac, I presume it's similar to Linux. That console output will tell you the reason.... most likely it's looking in the wrong place - depending on how Blender is started it could be running from within a directory you're not expecting... try using an absolute path to the file.

Comment: Indeed, the path was wrong... I changed for an absolute path, it worked "perfectly".

Comment: Instead of using operators to transform an object, it's better to just change its [`rotation_xxx` properties](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.rotation_axis_angle) directly. It'll be faster, you'll have more control over which objects to rotate, and it won't create unnecessary undo steps.

Comment: Thanks! I have another problem now. I want to check the file every x milliseconds. I can't seem to find a way to make threads or sleep work...

Comment: That is another question, so please ask it in another question. We'll be happy to answer that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rich has pointed out, the file you are trying to open does not reside at the location Blender starts up from.

By running `os.getcwd()` you can see, that you are working in the folder where you installed Blender to.

To open the file (which I guess is residing in your *homefolder*), you can use the **os.path** module:

```
os.path.expanduser('~')
```

This will give you your *homefolder*, which you can then combine with other directories using

```
os.path.join(direc1, direc2, file)
```

Another option is to use `os.chdir(directory)` to move to a new working directory first, before opening the file (e.g. you can use `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` to move to the folder where your python file sits)

Happy coding, Mr. Anderson!

**Hint:** When using different operation systems, make sure you always use the **os.path** module, as it can handle the differences in path separators ('\ for Windows, / for Linux and so on). E.g. `os.path.abspath(filepath)` to get a proper absolute path for the provided filepath.